# Should I tell my employer coworker is suing?

Tags: law

A coworker is thinking about suing my employer and has asked me to create a statement that says I was a witness to the reason as to why she is suing.

Should I tell my employer that she is considering this and can I be affected if I cooperate or even tell them this may be happen?

Comment: Is your company aware of the incident that the coworker is considering suing about?  If they are not aware of the incident you may have an obligation to report it depending on what it was.

Comment: Also before you sign anything get your own legal counsel to review it and protect yourself.

Comment: You should tell your coworker that they should summon you to testify.  This way you are legally obligated to make the statement.  If you offer to sign something then you are making that choice, and that decision, could land you in some hot water once the company realizes you volunteered to sign the statement.  As to if the company would be willing to violate your own rights, well if a coworker is preparing to sue the company, I would say it is at least possible.  In the end you should watch out for yourself.

Comment: That thing where he asks you to make a statement is called an interrogatory, and it's part of the discovery process **inside** a lawsuit.  And it is compulsory, so the employer can't blame you for complying.   It's all very formal, certified letter, service, **and sharing with the other side**.   As a friend, you cooperate with the service process to save money.  Narcing to the employer could get you in legal trouble IMO by upsetting his legal strategy.  Bypassing the interrogatory process will be judged harshly by the employer. Who WILL see it.

Answer (score 8):

Don't get involved.

If you're forced into an involvement, then consult a lawyer before you commit to getting involved.

Assume the worst will happen if you do get involved without taking advice first.

Answer (score 7):

> Should I tell my employer that she is considering this?

No you should not tell your employer that a coworker is "considering" suing them.

You don't really know what your coworker will decide to do in the end.

> Can I be affected if I cooperate or even tell them this may be happen?

Yes you could be affected.

If it gets out that you are supporting a lawsuit, there could be repercussions. Perhaps not overt, but the company may trust you less or even try to find a way to retaliate.

And if you tip off your employer, the coworker may be very resentful and might try to get back at you.

Depending on your feelings about the reasons behind the potential lawsuit, you might still choose to be involved. But you want to make that decision with your eyes open.

Comment: Worth noting that giving the company "a heads up" about the potential law suit will also not protect the OP from any repercussions of supporting said lawsuit.  So you just end up pissing off *both sides*.

Comment: @Steve-O - Worth pointing out that, only one of those sides, gives him a check every pay period.  So it might be important to avoid making that side upset.

Answer (score 0):

> A coworker is thinking about suing my employer and has asked me to create a statement that says I was a witness to the reason as to why she is suing.

Don't even consider it. Depending on where you live / work, this could potentially see you kicked out of your current job and make it very hard to find a new one (do you think future employers will want to take a risk on someone who helped to sue their old company?)